# How to Setting Up Multiple Data Directory in Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

How to Setting Up Multiple Data Directory in Mysql?

How to use of Mysql Database Without install Mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st question - [Setting Up Multiple Data Directories](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-data-directories.html)

For the 2nd question - the only way I know of that you could connect to a MySql Database without installing it is connecting to one not installed on your machine.  For information on using MySql with Java (since you have tagged this with "java" and "mysql"), please see [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)